# Casting on objects implementing unrelated interfaces Java

Tags: java

```
    class inher1
    {

    public static void main(String...args)
    {

     eat i = new ursus();


      if(i instanceof eat) System.out.println("Instance of eat");

 //Line 1
 if((omnivora)i instanceof eat) System.out.println("Instance of eat"); 
 //Line 2
if((omnivora)i instanceof omnivora) System.out.println("Instance of omnivora"); 

 if(((omnivora)i).like_honey)System.out.println("Like Honey Obtained");

    }

    }

    interface eat //Interface 1
    {
        public void eat();
    }

    interface omnivora //Interface 2
    {
        final public static boolean like_honey = true;
    }
    abstract class mammalia implements eat
    {
      abstract public void makenoise();
      public void eat(){System.out.println("Yummy");}
    }

    class ursus extends mammalia implements omnivora
    {
        public void makenoise(){System.out.println("Growl");}


    }

    class felidae extends mammalia
    {
        public void makenoise(){System.out.println("Roar");}
    }
```

This is my hierarchy

Eat and Omnivora are unrelated interfaces

Mammalia implements Eat Interface

Ursus extends Mammalia implements Omnivora interface

Felidae extends Mammalia

As it can be seen omnivora and eat are unrelated interfaces but yet both Line 1 and Line 2 prints "Instance of eat" and "Instance of omnivora" respectively.

Can someone tell me why ?

Comment: Please remember that Interface names and Class names should start in an upper-case; not a lower-case.

Comment: indirect implementation of both interface because " Ursus extends Mammalia implements Omnivora interface" (mammalia implements eat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As it can be seen omnivora and eat are unrelated interfaces but yet both Line 1 and Line 2 prints "Instance of eat" and "Instance of omnivora" respectively.
>
> Can someone tell me why ?

Because the object you're testing is an `ursus`, which implements `omnivora` and also implements `eat` (by inheriting from `mammalia`).

One of the key things about interfaces is that a class can implement multiple, unrelated interfaces, and its instances are considered "instances of" each of those interfaces.

A concrete example would be [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html), which extends `Reader` but also implements `Readable`, `Closeable`, and `AutoCloseable`. Those last two are unrelated to *reading*, per se, but the class's instances are instances of all of those interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

`Mammalia` implements both `eat` and `omnivora`, which means that any of the subclasses of `Mammalia` is a subtype of both of these interfaces.  So any `ursus` object is both an `eat` and an `omnivora`.

Answer (score 1):

Operator `instanceof` doesn't check against the `static` type of an object but against its `dynamic` type.  `(omnivora)i instanceof eat` is exactly the same as `i instanceof eat`.

No matter how much you cast it, the dynamic type of `i` is `ursus`, which is a subclass of `eat` and `omnivora`.  The result can't be different to what you are obtaining.

Please respect Java's naming conventions.  Your program is extremely difficult to read.